# Why is my keyframe timing function being ignored?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a spritesheet with multiple rows of sprites.
My keyframes work fine but for the timing function.

There are 39 sprites and so I need 39 steps without "tweening", however despite correct syntax my stepping time function is ignored.

```
animation: gem 10s steps(39) infinite;
```

Here is a jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Hd5Qy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found that timing functions are "per frame" so by setting the steps to 1, it would only show a single frame and then the next without tweening.

```
animation: gem 10s steps(1) infinite;
```

Check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/krazyjakee/Hd5Qy/5/

Comment: I think you can check your own answer as the official answer.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" - I'll be back.